# PyCharm warns about unexpected arguments for SQLAlchemy User model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pycharm, flask-login

I'm working with Flask-SQLAlchemy in PyCharm. When I try to create instances of my `User` model by passing keyword arguments to the model, PyCharm highlights the arguments with an "Unexpected argument(s)" warning. When I create instances of other models, I don't get this warning. Why am I getting this error for my `User` model?

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)

new_user = User(username="test")
```

In the above example `username="test"` is highlighted as a warning.

[image: warning in PyCharm]

Comment: Sadly, PyCharm's support for SQLAlchemy is still inclomplete. It can be followed here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-4536

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[This is a bug in PyCharm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-28663), not your code. PyCharm doesn't recognize column names as arguments when using mixins. You can show your interest in the issue by clicking the thumbs up button next to its title. Until then, there's nothing you can do to fix the issue besides disabling the inspection or ignoring the highlighting.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this annoying issue is to add a comment `# type: ignore` to the line, which removes Pycharm's type checking on that line and looks a lot nicer:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)

new_user = User(username="test")  # type: ignore[call-arg]
```

Comment: This doesn’t solve the issue, it just hides it.

Comment: @bfontaine yes, like I said it just removes Pycharm's typechecking which is sometimes what someone might want. the downvote was 100% unnecessary

Comment: A better solution would be to remove the specific warning without disabling the typechecking altogether (`type: ignore[call-arg]`)

Comment: @bfontaine i disagree

Comment: Compare `User(id=2+"bar") # type: ignore` and `User(id=2+"bar") # type: ignore[call-arg]`. In both cases you avoid the bogus "Unexpected argument" warning, but in the second one you still get the warning for `2+"bar"` that’s silenced in the first case.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to solve without a lot of effort, you can use type hints on more recent versions of python.

When defining your class, simply place the type hint directly into the declaration:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id: db.Column = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username: db.Column = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
```

If you do this for all tables, it does turn out a bit verbose, but it will also be fully functional for all linters, not just PyCharm.

Comment: question doesn't appear to involve `mypy`... was this an un-stated requirement?

Comment: what im trying to imply is that this has nothing to do with pycharm. Other type systems have the same problem. I would even guess pycharm is using mypy under the hood.

Comment: It has everything to do with PyCharm, as you can see with the link in the accepted answer.